# Split colon- and equal-separated string into several columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe , a column of which contains colon and equal-separated strings.

```
data$col1
  [1] "ECNT=2;HCNT=4;NLOD=38.78;MAX_ED=51;MIN_ED=51;TLOD=5.45"  
  [2] "ECNT=2;HCNT=8;MAX_ED=51;MIN_ED=51;NLOD=36.58;TLOD=4.05"  
  [3] "DB;ECNT=1;NLOD=20.42;HCNT=16;TLOD=5.82;MAX_ED=.;MIN_ED=."
  [4] "DB;ECNT=1;HCNT=4;MAX_ED=.;MIN_ED=.;NLOD=30.70;TLOD=8.03" 
  [5] "ECNT=2;HCNT=6;MAX_ED=7;MIN_ED=7;NLOD=41.48;TLOD=5.37"    
  [6] "ECNT=2;HCNT=9;MAX_ED=7;MIN_ED=7;NLOD=40.59;TLOD=5.29"
```

I want to extract the numbers follow the NLOD= and TLOD=, and then split it into two columns. Here is the output I want.

```
data
                                                        col1     TLOD      NLOD
    "ECNT=2;HCNT=4;NLOD=38.78;MAX_ED=51;MIN_ED=51;TLOD=5.45"     5.45     38.78
    "ECNT=2;HCNT=8;MAX_ED=51;MIN_ED=51;NLOD=36.58;TLOD=4.05"     4.05     36.58
  "DB;ECNT=1;NLOD=20.42;HCNT=16;TLOD=5.82;MAX_ED=.;MIN_ED=."     5.82     20.42
   "DB;ECNT=1;HCNT=4;MAX_ED=.;MIN_ED=.;NLOD=30.70;TLOD=8.03"     8.03     30.70
      "ECNT=2;HCNT=6;MAX_ED=7;MIN_ED=7;NLOD=41.48;TLOD=5.37"     5.37     41.48
      "ECNT=2;HCNT=9;MAX_ED=7;MIN_ED=7;NLOD=40.59;TLOD=5.29"     5.29     40.59
```

Reproducible sample data.

```
structure(list(col1 = c("ECNT=2;HCNT=4;NLOD=38.78;MAX_ED=51;MIN_ED=51;TLOD=5.45", 
"ECNT=2;HCNT=8;MAX_ED=51;MIN_ED=51;NLOD=36.58;TLOD=4.05", "DB;ECNT=1;NLOD=20.42;HCNT=16;TLOD=5.82;MAX_ED=.;MIN_ED=.", 
"DB;ECNT=1;HCNT=4;MAX_ED=.;MIN_ED=.;NLOD=30.70;TLOD=8.03", "ECNT=2;HCNT=6;MAX_ED=7;MIN_ED=7;NLOD=41.48;TLOD=5.37", 
"ECNT=2;HCNT=9;MAX_ED=7;MIN_ED=7;NLOD=40.59;TLOD=5.29")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @AnoushiravanR It seems that they are asking the same question, but now with the fields out of order. Note that it is the same person asking. I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @slamballais Yes you are right. At first I thought there might be a difference but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sub` here, for a base R option:

```r
df$TLOD <- sub("^.*\\bTLOD=(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\b.*$", "\\1", data$col1)
df$NLOD <- sub("^.*\\bNLOD=(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\b.*$", "\\1", data$col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract` and positive lookbehind `(?<=...)`to assert that the numbers we want to extract, expressed as a character class allowing only digits and `.`, are preceded by the substrings `TLOD=` and `NLOD` respectively:

```
library(stringr)
df$TLOD <- str_extract(df$col1, "(?<=TLOD=)[0-9.]+")
df$NLOD <- str_extract(df$col1, "(?<=NLOD=)[0-9.]+")
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  col1                                                     TLOD  NLOD 
  <chr>                                                    <chr> <chr>
1 ECNT=2;HCNT=4;NLOD=38.78;MAX_ED=51;MIN_ED=51;TLOD=5.45   5.45  38.78
2 ECNT=2;HCNT=8;MAX_ED=51;MIN_ED=51;NLOD=36.58;TLOD=4.05   4.05  36.58
3 DB;ECNT=1;NLOD=20.42;HCNT=16;TLOD=5.82;MAX_ED=.;MIN_ED=. 5.82  20.42
4 DB;ECNT=1;HCNT=4;MAX_ED=.;MIN_ED=.;NLOD=30.70;TLOD=8.03  8.03  30.70
5 ECNT=2;HCNT=6;MAX_ED=7;MIN_ED=7;NLOD=41.48;TLOD=5.37     5.37  41.48
6 ECNT=2;HCNT=9;MAX_ED=7;MIN_ED=7;NLOD=40.59;TLOD=5.29     5.29  40.59
```